# need to show multiple symbols for one point

Tags: symbology, layers

I am working on a state map of parks with campsites. I want to show symbols for handicap access, tent camping, backpack camping, winter camping, rv camping. I have used a symbol for handicap but it shows up multiple times at some parks. Also if there is more than one type of camping it is over shadowed by handicap. any ideas? thanks

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Very similar to [How to place multiple symbols on one polygon centroid?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16154/how-to-place-multiple-symbols-on-one-polygon-centroid)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which software package you're using but here's a link related to [Categorizing Features in ArcMap](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Drawing_features_to_show_categories).  If you look in the left pane, you'll see numerous other links that might also assist you with advanced symbology options.  Do some reading and I'm sure you'll find your answers.   You'll also notice another drop down arrow just below this category titled "Styles & Symbols".  You may also find some useful information at those links.